# Force "bad" (not 0) return code of terminal command?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts

I have a framework written in python, and for testing purposes I basically want to do a subprocess (aka shell call) ... that should simply come back with a RC != 0. I tried to invoke some non-existing executable; or to run "exit 1"; but those are for some reason translated to a FileNotFoundError.

So, what else could I do to trigger a return code != 0 (in a "reliable" way; meaning the command should not suddenly return 0 at a future point in time).

I thought to "search" for a binary called exit, but well:

```
> /usr/bin/env exit
/usr/bin/env: exit: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `exit 1` is the future-proof way to go. The FileNotFoundError must be caused by something else.

Comment: When I do "which exit" ... nothing is found. So I assume that "exit" is a bash function; probably not available when I do a subprocess call?!

Comment: Technical nitpicking: a non-zero return code is not intended as an indication of a *bad* situation, as your question seems to imply. That "0" means "nothing wrong" is just a matter of convention. In fact you have 8 bits of information to convey back to the calling process.

Comment: @Jos I understand that. But the point is that a RC!=0 leads to a specific exception from subprocess.check_call(). I want to enforce that condition to ensure it is properly handled (to make sure that any RC!=0 situation in real tests is handled as it should be).

Comment: You can find out the return code of the last shell command _inside the terminal(!)_ with executing `echo $?`. The `$?` variable contains the most recent return code and `echo` prints it to the standard output. You can create a new return code with the command `bash -c "exit RETURNCODE`, replacing "RETURNCODE" with any number. Note that it will be trimmed to an 8bit unsigned integer (0...255) by (RETURNCODE mod 256)

Comment: How about `/bin/false`?

Comment: @Jos Thanks. Fast enough to be able to edit and correct it. :)

Comment: @steeldriver /bin/false is exactly what I was looking for!  Feel free to turn your comment into an answer; so I can accept it.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, executing /bin/false always produces the return code 1.

Comment: @Jägermeister Note that `/bin/false`'s output is always 1. If you want return codes different than 1 (every integer value between 0 and 255 inclusive), you have to prefer my solution (`bash -c "exit RETURNCODE"`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're looking for a *system* command that always returns a non-zero exit code, then `/bin/false` seems like it should work for you. From `man false`:

```
NAME
       false - do nothing, unsuccessfully

SYNOPSIS
       false [ignored command line arguments]
       false OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Exit with a status code indicating failure.
```

Comment: No, it does not. At least on Ubuntu 16.04.4 running bash the following command line gives 1 instead of 5: `/bin/false 5; echo $?`

Comment: @fviktor it exits with *non-zero* status - as the synopsis says,  command line arguments (such as `5`) are ignored

Comment: You're right. Just no way to control the actual non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a new return code with the command `bash -c "exit RETURNCODE"`, replacing "RETURNCODE" with any number. Note that it will be trimmed to an 8bit unsigned integer (0...255) by (RETURNCODE mod 256)

You can check the return code of the last shell command *inside the terminal(!)* with executing `echo $?`. The "$?" variable contains the most recent return code and "echo" prints it to the standard output.

Comment: +1. Note that if you're writing this in a shell script, you can just do `exit RETURNCODE` (without the `bash -c` part)

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, I found that my problem was not on the "Linux" side.

Python has a module shlex; which should be used to "split" command strings. When I changed my subprocess call to use the output of `shlex.split()` invoking "bash exit 1" gives me what I need.